# Searching the derived object by pointer of base type

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

So I have 4 classes defined like that:

```
class Body
{//not important};

class CelestialBody: public Body
{//not important}

class Star: public CelestialBody
{//not important}

class Starship: public Body
{//not important}
```

And then I define vectors of shared_ptrs of those objects:

```
vector<shared_ptr<Starship> > starships;
vector<shared_ptr<CelestialBody> > planetoids;
vector<shared_ptr<Star> > stars;
vector<Body*> bodies;
```

Which then I fill with objects:

```
for(int i=0; i<1; ++i)
{
    starships.push_back(shared_ptr<Starship>(new Starship));
    bodies.push_back(starships[starships.size()-1].get());
}
for(int i=0; i<totalOfBodies; ++i)
{
    planetoids.push_back(shared_ptr<CelestialBody>(new CelestialBody));
    bodies.push_back(planetoids[planetoids.size()-1].get());
}
for(int i=0; i<0; ++i)
{
    stars.push_back(shared_ptr<Star>(new Star));
    bodies.push_back(stars[stars.size()-1].get());
}
```

It all works as I want: I have a vector to reach all bodies, I have a vector to reach specifically  all planetoids, all stars and all starships. But now I want to delete a starship from both `bodies` vector and `starships` vector, but I only know its index in the `bodies` vector:

```
if(bodies[j]->Type() == starshipType) 
{
    starships.erase(find(starships.begin(), starships.end(), bodies[j]));
    //error:  no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘std::shared_ptr<Starship>’ and ‘Body* const’)

}
bodies.erase(bodies.begin() + j);
```

I understand the error it produces, but I don't know how to do that instead.

Bo basically I want a big vector holding all the objects that are Bodies (so children too) and few smaller ones that hold objects of separate types, but I still want to retain the possibility to delete objects from both big vector and the specific vector.

EDIT:

Ok, so basically I've missed defining `bodies` as `vector<shared_ptr<Body> >`.
But the section with finding doesn't work:

```
starships.erase(find(starships.begin(), starships.end(), bodies[j]));
```

I'm searching for `shared_ptr<Body>` in a vector of `shared_ptr<Starship>` which always returns end of vector. How can I search for object of derived class while having a object sliced version of it?

ANOTHER EDIT:

Thanks for quick response. I think `std::find_if()` along with id system will suit me.

Comment: You should be aware of [`std::vector::back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back). It returns a reference to the last element of the vector. You should also be made aware of [`std::make_shared<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) which is the preferred way of creating an instance owned by a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Why do you have the `bodies` vector be a vector of non-shared pointers? That just begs for stray pointers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If the vectors of `shared_ptr` have the same life time as `bodies`, it's fine. Nothing wrong with non-owning pointers. Smart pointers and raw pointers are both tools with their pros and cons. Use whichever is appropriate for the job.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yes but that's a big "if". I'm more worried about the other case where the "if" is not true, and the shared pointer releases its data before it is removed from the `bodies` vector. While it might not be the case currently, just having the risk being there is enough for me to question that choice.

Comment: Incidentally, having `bodies` be a vector of shared pointers to the base class will solve the current problem with the comparison.

Comment: I assume you're after some polymorphic behavior, so why `vector< shared_ptr<Body> > bodies;` is not enough?

Comment: This sounds like a case for `std::weak_ptr`.  `bodies` can be a `std::vector<std::weak_ptr<Body>>` and then it is trivial to `erase` and `remove` all `expired` pointers.

Comment: there is an option to add field ID to base Body, and instead of using vectors use maps with ID as a key, so you will have no problems finding something.

Comment: "object sliced version of it" huh? Anyway, try `std::find_if`.